# Is it possible to install an older Boost library on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boost

I'm trying to install **libboost1.46-all-dev on Ubuntu 13.04** because it's necessary for our project.

Unfortunately I was not able to find it in my repos while doing

```
sudo apt-cache search libboost1.49-all-dev
```

Default is actually libboost1.46-all-dev. Does anyone has an idea where I can find the older package and install it using apt-get ?

Comment: You can download the sources from boost.org, and build them with `./bjam`

Comment: I see. I guess I have to do it this way. But there is no way to use the package manager? Thanks anyway.

Comment: perhaps you can [forcibly install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213589/how-to-install-a-older-version-of-package-like-liquid-2-2-2) older an package, but I'm not sure you will find the specific version you need. Building boost is quite simple, and it would be the easiest way to do what you need.